# Type error when using 'map' - Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, types

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

flipsOneY :: Point -> (Int, Int) -> Point
flipsOneY point (i, j) = ((fst point), ((fromIntegral j) - (snd point)))

changeY :: [Point] -> (Int, Int) -> [Point]
changeY xs (i, j) = map flipsOneY xs (i, j)
```

I have a list of points (x, y) where i want to change the value of the Y coordinate. When i try to compile this i recieve this error:

```
Expr.hs:149:21:
Couldn't match expected type `(Int, Int) -> Point'
            with actual type `[(Int, Int) -> Point]'
The function `map' is applied to three arguments,
but its type `(Point -> (Int, Int) -> Point)
              -> [Point] -> [(Int, Int) -> Point]'
has only two
In the expression: map flipsOneY xs (i, j)
In an equation for `changeY':
    changeY xs (i, j) = map flipsOneY xs (i, j)
```

I am guessing i am not using map correctly. Any hint towards a solution is appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

flipsOneY :: Point -> (Int, Int) -> Point
flipsOneY point (i, j) = ((fst point), ((fromIntegral j) - (snd point)))

changeY :: [Point] -> (Int, Int) -> [Point]
changeY xs (i, j) = map flipsOneY xs (i, j)
```

`map` takes 2 arguments but you are passing it three.

Try putting parenthesis around the `flipOnesY` call, like so:

```
changeY :: [Point] -> (Int, Int) -> [Point]
changeY xs (i, j) = map (\ys -> flipsOneY ys (i, j)) xs
```

This also shows you that your argument order to flipsOneY is not optimal.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "not optimal" part?  I think an example of how to make it more optimal would be very useful for @Rewbert.

Comment: This solved my problem, and i am always up for some extra tips to learn more. :) Would the code me better if i simple changed the order of the arguments, or are there bigger flaws to take into account?
 I remember seeing you comment alot on my threads these past weeks @bheklilr Thanks, i've learned alot these weeks. Almost done with my first functional programming course :)

Comment: @Rewbert Yes, if you swapped the argument order of `flipsOneY`, then you could define `changeY` as `changeY xs ij = map (flipsOneY ij) xs` or if you swapped the order of the arguments in `changeY` you could go pointfree with `changeY ij = map (flipsOneY ij)`.

Comment: Point free inner labmda: `changeY xs t = map (flip flipsOneY t) xs`. If you now change the order of the outer parameter, you get: `changeY = map . flip flipsOneY`

Comment: So you could also write (with the current order): `changeY = flip $ map . flip flipsOneY`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn This is true, but I usually prefer to avoid using `flip` if I can rearrange the order of the arguments in the definition.  I just think it looks cleaner and makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: I agree. Best case would be `changeY = map . flipsOneY` with the order of `flipsOneY` and `changeY`